# Cargar contenido sin recargar la página con Angular

Tags: angularjs

Quisiera saber como cargar otros componentes sin tener recargar la página en **Angular 4.**

Saludos.

---

Una solución poco prolija que hice, fue creando funciones para ocultar y mostrar la información

`function Agregar(){
    $('#texto').css("display", "block");
    $('#data').css("display", "none");
}`

Comment: Ya has consultado información acerca de las directivas? Por ahí puedes iniciar

Comment: Si estas usando un navbar te recomiendo uses el tema de ruteo; si estas cargando contenido de servicios te recomiendo llames al servicio, mediante un metodo y y agreges de nuevo los campos que obtuviste dentro de un arreglo o lo que sea que estes usando

Answer (score 0):

con un routerlink puedes probar cargar los componentes sin recargar la pagina`

```
@Directive({ selector: ':not(a)[routerLink]' })
class RouterLink {
  queryParams: {[k: string]: any}
  fragment: string
  queryParamsHandling: QueryParamsHandling
  preserveFragment: boolean
  skipLocationChange: boolean
  replaceUrl: boolean
  set routerLink: any[]|string
  set preserveQueryParams: boolean
  onClick(): boolean
  get urlTree: UrlTree
}
```

`

Answer (score -1):

No estoy muy seguro por qué dices que necesitas recargar la página con angular 4 , en angular toda la aplicación es una página única, supongo que te refieres a poder navegar en múltiples vistas, y en dicho caso lo que necesitas es manejar rutas, un tutorial sencillo de cómo configurar y usar las rutas lo puedes encontrar en la   [documentación de angular](https://angular.io/guide/router), pero la idea es configurar las rutas en tu archivo app.module.ts como muestro a continuación

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/heroes',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
    // other imports here
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Si observas se declara un arreglo con los componentes  y la ruta a la que responderá la URL del navegador.